# What's wrong in this simple javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a program which can sum up all the digits in a given number. I want my script to return the resul on click of the button Please help me find error in my code. Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sumdigits()
{
    var num=document.getElementById("a").value;
    var len=num.length();
    alert(len);

    if(len!=0)
    {
        var sum=0;
        var ldigit=0;

        while(num!=0)
        {
            ldigit=num%10;
            sum+=ldigit;
            num/=10;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sum of digits of the given number="+sum;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    Enter a number: <input type="text" id="a" name="t1"><br/>
    <input type="button" name="sub" value="Submit" onClick="sumdigits()">
    <div id="result">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what's going wrong.

Comment: other than `num` being a string and you trying to use it in math operations?

Comment: length() is not a function. You may want num.length

Comment: Also, your HTML is malformed. `<input />` tags should be self-closing. You're missing the slash before the closing angled bracket.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw That's not required by HTML. It can still be a good suggestion. But, it's not missing or malformed.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome have a Javascript Console which can be reached via Ctrl-Shift-J. Please post their output here.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks for the corrective--something that passed me by these past few years of working on desktop apps.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AnOkAWAl/2/edit)

`onClick` should be `onclick`, `length()` should be `length` and `sum` not out of scope

```
function sumdigits(){

    var num = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var len = num.length;   // note "length"
    var sum;                // "sum" scope
    alert(len);

    if(len!==0){
        sum = 0;
        var ldigit=0;

        while(num!==0){
            ldigit=num%10;
            sum += ldigit;
            num /= 10;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sum of digits of the given number = "+ sum;

}
```

This is how to make it work, now, I don't know what math you're trying to apply in there and what's it's purpose...

Comment: Thanks @Roko C. Buljain for correction. Basically I made a silly mistake or you say a blunder mistake in case of calculating length of the variable num. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main reason the script is breaking is because you are calling length() on num variable instead of num.length. Below is a link to a working fiddle with that and a few other adjustments made ( check to see if the value's are integers etc...).

http://jsbin.com/uBAyOJep/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit="sumdigits()">
    Enter a number: <input type="text" id="a" name="t1"><br/>
    <input type="button" name="sub" value="Submit" onClick="sumdigits()">
    <div id="result">&nbsp;</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

function sumdigits()
{
    var sum = 0,
        num = document.getElementById("a").value,
        len = num.length,
        result = document.getElementById("result");

    if( len !== 0 ){
        for( var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            var lineValue = parseInt(num[i], 0);
            if ( !isNaN(lineValue) ) {
                sum += lineValue;
            }
        }
    }

    result.innerHTML="Sum of digits of the given numbers = " + sum;

}
```